# Access local html page via ip , but should not access with hostname

Tags: linux, apache, http, centos

My requirement is simple. When i try to access a html page in localhost using ip (https://ip) i must connect/able to access that site. But when i try to access  that same page using hostname (https://hostname) it should not load/access that page. Is it possible to do so?

I tried with redirect and rewrite conditions, but none of that works.
Thank you..

Comment: Can you share the rewrite rules that you tried with?

Comment: Not much rewrite rules were applied, just some simple basic rules. And i'm sorry i almost forgot everything, last thing i did was: Redirect 403 /